# How we can enable SSO identity server 4?

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

Should I Create only one client and all my applications must connect to the identity server using it or there is configuration should I do to make it work?

Identity Server is Web API, grant type is "resource owner password".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each application is a client. But whether you should use the same client_id is up to you. Personally I use different client_id's for each instance of an application. This helps me to identify the instance and allows me to use different secrets per instance. And I think that the client_id has to be unique when you are using refresh tokens.

SSO is something you get for free when you use OpenId Connect (oidc). It works because of a cookie on the IdentityServer website:

When a user has to log in, the user is redirected to the IdentityServer website where (after succesful authentication) a cookie is set, containing information about the identity of the user.

When the user is returned to the client (after succesful authentication) the client will also set a cookie. As long as this authentication cookie is available, the user will be logged in.

When the user needs to log in again, because the client can't authenticate the user (anymore), IdentityServer will try to identify the user with the information from the cookie on the IdentityServer website and (if succesful) automatically sign in the user, skipping the login form.

---

But it seems that your setup has nothing to do with oidc. When you say that IdentityServer is a Web Api then this suggests that the user is not redirected to the IdentityServer to login, meaning that there is no opportunity to set a cookie.

And Resource Owner Password Credentials (ROPC) is an OAuth2 grant type. This suggests that the user performs the login on the client.

In order to enable SSO, the user has to login on the IdentityServer website. While ROPC is still possible, you'd better use one of the recommended [grant types](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html).

Comment: How it's still possible to achieve SSO while using ROPC?                                                     and how I can manage different claims based on client when enabling SSO?

Comment: SSO depends on the cookie on the IdentityServer website. Instead of having a client side login form make sure to redirect the user to the IdentityServer website where the user can login, allowing IdentityServer to set the cookie.

Comment: Claims are added regardless how the user was authenticated. So it doesn't matter which flow you are using and if authentication was the result of automatic authentication (SSO). Why would there be a difference? You can include information about the used grant type, but I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: thanks for reply, my question is if I have multiple clients and each client has its own claims how SSO will handle this?

Comment: Claims are configured in IdentityServer per client (and by that I mean unique client_id). You can configure the allowed grant types, urls, allowed scopes, etc. The user claims are used as resource in order to add claims to the identity token (identity resource claims) or the access token (api resource claims). But like I said before, this is not related to the method used to authenticate the user. If you have multiple applications where you need a different set of claims, then you'll have to configure these applications as seperate clients (unique client_id).