# SSO with OpenID connect?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect

The spec says
*3.1.2.3.  Authorization Server Authenticates End-User
The methods used by the Authorization Server to Authenticate the End-User (e.g. username and password, session cookies, etc.) **are beyond the scope of this specification**.*

How does SSO work with OpenID Connect?

Are cookies used? Is "id_token_hint" used?

I could not find anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

Its implementation specific, but typically when you login at the authorization server, you receive a login session cookie with the server that is used to give you the SSO experience.

You can use the id_token_hint to pass your ID-token when you authenticate with a new app to get a more smooth login experience.

Comment: Thank you. I have explored the documentation of a few implementations, and not many details provided, very high level flows. Any other approaches besides cookies and  id_token_hint?

Comment: It vary from implementation to implementation, so you have to review the documents for the OIDC server you are using. Also, the user needs to consent once to the scopes for each service and that is typically different  form application to application. What SSO server are you look at? see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62615146/how-we-can-enable-sso-identity-server-4

Comment: I was exploring curity.io and cyberark. No implementation details about SSO. Regarding the link to thinktecture's Id Server - I have worked with it, and if I am not wrong, a cookie is used but it will contain just a session identifier. The full info is available only on the server. I was hoping that providers would provide more details about their flows.

Comment: I think using cookies is the way most implementations do it. You can always explore the cookies and tokens used in for example Google